# How to Auto-deploy with Jboss

Tags: automation, jboss

How to automatically deploy a project with jboss as 7. Is there a way to automatically deploy a Project using the Jboss-cli.sh in Jboss as 7?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching the Internet for this answer and could not find it. I recently figured it out and thought I would share. I wrote a linux shell script that works perfectly. Taking the time to deploy while developing from 2-3 minutes to 10 seconds which makes programming so much faster.
Here is my script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

cd /home/samo/EAP*/bin
./jboss-cli.sh --connect <<EOF
undeploy FlcErp.ear
deploy /home/samo/NetBeansProjects/FlcErp/FlcErp/dist/FlcErp.ear
EOF
```

first line of the script navigates to the location of your server bin. 
the second line opens `jboss-cli.sh` and connects to the instance. 
everything after `<<EOF` and before `EOF` are commands you can send to the jboss-cli.sh program. In this case I `undeploy` my current instance which is `FlcErp.ear` then I `deploy` the full location of my project.

You then save this file the file with your desired name `"Deploy"` change the permission with `chmod 755 Deploy`

Then add this file to your path with: `export $PATH = $PATH:/home/samo/bin`

to execute file just type filename into terminal